# My first Haskell: dice rolling

Tags: beginner, haskell, dice

Yesterday morning I decided to stop procrastinating and start learning me some Haskell.

So far I've made this, which is a simple cli 'dice rolling' utility that can be used like:

```
$ ./dice 3d20
You rolled: 17
```

The code looks like this:

```
import Data.List.Split
import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Random
import System.Environment


type Dice = (Int, Int)

diceCode :: String -> Dice
diceCode die = (parts!!0, parts!!1)
  where
    parts = [read x :: Int | x <- take 2 (splitOn "D" (map toUpper die))]


rollDie :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> Rand g Int
rollDie sides = getRandomR (1, sides)

rollDice :: (RandomGen g) => Dice -> Rand g Int
rollDice dice = liftM sum (sequence(replicate rolls (rollDie sides)))
  where
    rolls = fst dice
    sides = snd dice


main = do
  args <- getArgs
  roll <- evalRandIO (rollDice (diceCode (args!!0)))
  putStrLn ("You rolled: " ++ show roll)
```

I was able to get the `diceCode` 'parsing' function by myself without too much trouble.

The `rollDie` function is almost straight from [an example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.4.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html#g:2) in the `Control.Monad.Random` docs, which helped a lot.

I struggled for quite a while to find a recipe for summing the rolls in `rollDice`... it seemed to me I ought to use [`msum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:msum) but I couldn't find a way to make it work. `liftM sum` seems to do exactly what I wanted though.

I also found the use of tuples quite cumbersome. In Python I could just do:
    `rolls, sides = dice`
but I seem to have to use the horribly-named `fst` and `snd` functions to access the members in Haskell (?)

I guess the next part of my adventure is to try and incorporate this into a larger program, eg a simple game.  It seems like the monadically-wrapped random int values are going to force the rest of the code to be 'monad-aware' (i.e. lots of use of `liftM`) and I wonder if there is a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list comprehension you use in `diceCode` is a bit overkill: after all, you only want to split the list of characters into two. You can use `break` instead.

Here I have to use `fmap tail` to act on the second list because `break` retains the value it breaks the list at (the 'd' character here). This would be a good place to handle the sort of errors that would arise if there is no 'd' in the string.

```
diceCode :: String -> Dice
diceCode die = (read rolls, read sides) where
  (rolls, sides) = fmap tail $ break ('D' ==) $ fmap toUpper die
```

Your `rollDice` is a bit complex. Here is how I would rewrite it:

- `(rolls, sides)` on the left hand side exposes the two components of the tuple
- `[1..rolls]` generates a list of length `rolls`
- `mapM (const $ rollDie sides)` replaces all the numbers in that list with an invocation of `rollDie sides` *and* performs the same job as `sequence` thus returning an `Random g [Int]`
- `sum <$>` (or `fmap sum $`) goes under the `Random g` part and sums the elements in the `[Int]` value.

Putting all this together we get:

```
rollDice :: (RandomGen g) => Dice -> Rand g Int
rollDice (rolls, sides) = sum <$> mapM (const $ rollDie sides) [1..rolls]
```

The rest of the code is quite idiomatic. One thing I was a bit concerned about is the fact that a `Dice` is represented as a pair of `Int`s: to understand which is which, you need to read the code manipulating them and if you make a mistake the compiler won't warn you: they have the same type! It's quite annoying. One thing you could do is use a record type instead in order to *name* the two fields:

```
data Dice' = Dice' { rolls :: Int
                   , sides :: Int }
```

This way you can access them by their names, build the `Dice'` using the named syntax, etc.

Comment: thanks, I will digest this a bit. first question - I'm just googling what is `fmap` and why not `map`... it seems like `fmap` is more 'general' and I should always just use it instead of `map`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6824333/202168

Comment: I don't understand why`fmap tail` only strips the first char from the second half and not from the first half too. I tried in ghci `fmap tail ([1,2,3],[4,1,2,3,4])` returns `([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4])` ...I don't understand why this result

Comment: following your hint in 4th bullet point I wrote this line `rollDice (rolls, sides) = fmap sum $ sequence $ replicate rolls (rollDie sides)` which seems to work fine... however I don't understand why `fmap sum` is appropriate here (or even works). `liftM sum` made sense to me but now I am confused.

Comment: on the other hand, I just found this works `rollDice (rolls, sides) = sum <$> (sequence $ replicate rolls (rollDie sides))` ...this makes sense to me if I understand `<$>` as a sort of 'monadic `$`' or ...an infix `liftM`?  I had to add parentheses around the right-hand-side to get it to compile

Comment: `fmap` and `liftM` are the same thing.  As you noticed,`(<$>)` is a nice infix operator for it. It does not have the same precedence as `$` hence the fact that you needed to add parentheses to get haskell to parse the expression the right way.

Comment: `fmap` works for functors: it preserves the structure of its argument but alters the values inside. `fmap tail` is applied to a pair so the functor instance selected by Haskell is [Functor ((,) a)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-625) hence the fact that the function is applied to the second argument.

Comment: I have just remembered that you could use `replicateM` rather than `sequence $ replicate (...)`. Quite a lot of pure functions have effectful counterparts (with an appropriate suffix: "M" for Monad, or "A" for Applicative).

Comment: I'm going to have to read more about `fmap`, it's hurting my brain. If I understood the docs you linked it does different things depending on the type of the second arg. In ghci it does what I'd expect if passed a list, so this special behaviour for a pair seems a major WTF.  I'm sure there's good reason for this but I find it hard to conceptualise currently